# RichTextBox Spell Check

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, spell-checking

I have a RichTextBox and I would like to add a feature. Basically I've enabled the `SpellCheck.isEnabled = True` so whenever I misspell something, the red squiggly lines will be show.

The feature I'd like to add is the "Add Word" feature. Basically I was following this [`Tutorial`](http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/customize-spellcheck-in-wpf-textbox/) which shows you how to do exactly that. This tutorial uses a `WPF TextBox` and not a `WPF RichTextBox` so what I did was I tried my best to make it work for the `WPF RichTextBox`. My code for that is:

```
private void ctrl_RtfText_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    int index = 0;
    this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Clear(); //Clearing the existing items
    //Getting the spellcheck suggestions.
    SpellingError spellingError = this.ctrl_RtfText.GetSpellingError(this.ctrl_RtfText.CaretPosition);
    if (spellingError != null && spellingError.Suggestions.Count() >= 1)
    {
        //Creating the suggestions menu items.
        foreach (string suggestion in spellingError.Suggestions)
        {
            MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
            menuItem.Header = suggestion;
            menuItem.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            menuItem.Command = EditingCommands.CorrectSpellingError;
            menuItem.CommandParameter = suggestion;
            menuItem.CommandTarget = this.ctrl_RtfText;
            this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, menuItem);
            index++;
        }
        Separator seperator = new Separator();
        this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, seperator);
        index++;
        //Adding the IgnoreAll menu item
        MenuItem IgnoreAllMenuItem = new MenuItem();
        IgnoreAllMenuItem.Header = "Ignore All";
        IgnoreAllMenuItem.Command = EditingCommands.IgnoreSpellingError;
        IgnoreAllMenuItem.CommandTarget = this.ctrl_RtfText;
        this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, IgnoreAllMenuItem);
        index++;
    }
    else
    {
        //No Suggestions found, add a disabled NoSuggestions menuitem.
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
        menuItem.Header = "No Suggestions";
        menuItem.IsEnabled = false;
        this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, menuItem);
        index++;
    }
    //.Net 4.0 Supports CustomDictionaries, Option for Adding to dictionary.
    TextPointer selectionStart = ctrl_RtfText.Document.ContentStart;
    if (!(this.ctrl_RtfText.Selection.IsEmpty))
    {
        Separator seperator1 = new Separator();
        this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, seperator1);
        index++;
        MenuItem AddToDictionary = new MenuItem();
        AddToDictionary.Header = "Add to Dictionary";
        //Getting the word to add
        this.ctrl_RtfText.GetSpellingErrorRange(selectionStart);
        //Ignoring the added word.
        AddToDictionary.Command = EditingCommands.IgnoreSpellingError;
        AddToDictionary.CommandTarget = this.ctrl_RtfText;
        AddToDictionary.Click += (object o, RoutedEventArgs rea) =>
        {
            this.AddToDictionary(this.ctrl_RtfText.Selection.Text);
        };
        this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, AddToDictionary);
        index++;
    }

    //Common Edit MenuItems.
    Separator seperator2 = new Separator();
    this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, seperator2);
    index++;
    //Cut
    MenuItem cutMenuItem = new MenuItem();
    cutMenuItem.Command = ApplicationCommands.Cut;
    this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, cutMenuItem);
    index++;
    //Copy
    MenuItem copyMenuItem = new MenuItem();
    copyMenuItem.Command = ApplicationCommands.Copy;
    this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, copyMenuItem);
    index++;
    //Paste
    MenuItem pasteMenuItem = new MenuItem();
    pasteMenuItem.Command = ApplicationCommands.Paste;
    this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, pasteMenuItem);
    index++;
    Separator seperator3 = new Separator();
    this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, seperator3);
    index++;
    //Delete
    MenuItem deleteMenuItem = new MenuItem();
    deleteMenuItem.Command = ApplicationCommands.Delete;
    this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, deleteMenuItem);
    index++;
    Separator seperator4 = new Separator();
    this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, seperator4);
    index++;
    //Select All
    MenuItem selectAllMenuItem = new MenuItem();
    selectAllMenuItem.Command = ApplicationCommands.SelectAll;
    this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, selectAllMenuItem);
    index++;
}
//Method to Add text to Dictionary
private void AddToDictionary(string entry)
{
    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\New folder (2)\MyCustomDictionary.lex", true))
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(entry);
    }
}
```

**Now the Problem:**

Basically the Spell Checker, when there is a misspelled word the spell checker, when right clicked on the word, brings down a context menu and shows suggestion. The user can pick on one of the suggestions and the word fixes. This all happens without the user needing to highlight the word and then selecting the suggestions. Let me make it clear:

[image]

The user clicks on the prefered suggestion and it's corrected. Now My code basically only shows the "Add Word" feature when the selection of text is selected:

[image]

I want it so that, just like the previous image, when there is an error, the "Add Word" feature should be present with the rest of the suggestions etc..

Comment: Is the whole code related to the problem? All 106 lines?

Comment: 'if (!(this.ctrl_RtfText.Selection.IsEmpty))' Only that bit. I forgot to add that when the selection isn't empty then show the "Add Word" feature. I don't know how to get it when its simply just within the word, just like the tutorial.

Comment: This thread has taught me SO much : )  - Small error: The Delete menu item should call `EditingCommands.Delete` (not `ApplicationCommands.Delete`)

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error replace

```
SpellingError spellingError = this.ctrl_RtfText.GetSpellingError(this.ctrl_RtfText.CaretPosition);
if (spellingError != null && spellingError.Suggestions.Count() >= 1)
{
    //Creating the suggestions menu items.
    foreach (string suggestion in spellingError.Suggestions)
    {
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
        menuItem.Header = suggestion;
        menuItem.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        menuItem.Command = EditingCommands.CorrectSpellingError;
        menuItem.CommandParameter = suggestion;
        menuItem.CommandTarget = this.ctrl_RtfText;
        this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, menuItem);
        index++;
    }
    Separator seperator = new Separator();
    this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, seperator);
    index++;
    //Adding the IgnoreAll menu item
    MenuItem IgnoreAllMenuItem = new MenuItem();
    IgnoreAllMenuItem.Header = "Ignore All";
    IgnoreAllMenuItem.Command = EditingCommands.IgnoreSpellingError;
    IgnoreAllMenuItem.CommandTarget = this.ctrl_RtfText;
    this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, IgnoreAllMenuItem);
    index++;
}
else
{
    //No Suggestions found, add a disabled NoSuggestions menuitem.
    MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
    menuItem.Header = "No Suggestions";
    menuItem.IsEnabled = false;
    this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, menuItem);
    index++;
}
//.Net 4.0 Supports CustomDictionaries, Option for Adding to dictionary.
TextPointer selectionStart = ctrl_RtfText.Document.ContentStart;
if (!(this.ctrl_RtfText.Selection.IsEmpty))
{
    Separator seperator1 = new Separator();
    this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, seperator1);
    index++;
    MenuItem AddToDictionary = new MenuItem();
    AddToDictionary.Header = "Add to Dictionary";
    //Getting the word to add
    this.ctrl_RtfText.GetSpellingErrorRange(selectionStart);
    //Ignoring the added word.
    AddToDictionary.Command = EditingCommands.IgnoreSpellingError;
    AddToDictionary.CommandTarget = this.ctrl_RtfText;
    AddToDictionary.Click += (object o, RoutedEventArgs rea) =>
    {
        this.AddToDictionary(this.ctrl_RtfText.Selection.Text);
    };
    this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, AddToDictionary);
    index++;
}
//REST OF THE CODE
```

with

```
SpellingError spellingError = this.ctrl_RtfText.GetSpellingError(this.ctrl_RtfText.CaretPosition);
if (spellingError != null)
{
    //Creating the suggestions menu items.
    foreach (string suggestion in spellingError.Suggestions)
    {
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
        menuItem.Header = suggestion;
        menuItem.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        menuItem.Command = EditingCommands.CorrectSpellingError;
        menuItem.CommandParameter = suggestion;
        menuItem.CommandTarget = this.ctrl_RtfText;
        this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
    }
    if(this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Count == 0)
    {
         //No Suggestions found, add a disabled NoSuggestions menuitem.
         MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
         menuItem.Header = "No Suggestions";
         menuItem.IsEnabled = false;
         this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
    }
    Separator seperator = new Separator();
    this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Add(seperator);
    //Adding the IgnoreAll menu item
    MenuItem IgnoreAllMenuItem = new MenuItem();
    IgnoreAllMenuItem.Header = "Ignore All";
    IgnoreAllMenuItem.Command = EditingCommands.IgnoreSpellingError;
    IgnoreAllMenuItem.CommandTarget = this.ctrl_RtfText;
    this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Add(IgnoreAllMenuItem);
    Separator seperator1 = new Separator();
    this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Add(seperator1);

    MenuItem AddToDictionary = new MenuItem();
    AddToDictionary.Header = "Add to Dictionary";
    //Getting the word to add
    var tr = this.ctrl_RtfText.GetSpellingErrorRange(this.ctrl_RtfText.CaretPosition);
    //Ignoring the added word.
    AddToDictionary.Command = EditingCommands.IgnoreSpellingError;
    AddToDictionary.CommandTarget = this.ctrl_RtfText;
    AddToDictionary.Click += (object o, RoutedEventArgs rea) =>
    {
        this.AddToDictionary(tr.Text);
    };
    this.ctrl_RtfText.ContextMenu.Items.Add(AddToDictionary);
}
//REST OF THE CODE
```

This is a quick edit. Not sure if it runs without some minor tweaks.

Answer (score -1):

Download a EN_US.lang and than make it read the file, add the words then
Comment if you want me to show you how to do it!

Comment: Close the comment? Huh?